# order vector by value inside vector c++

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<vector<float>> tmp = {{1,10,5,4},{2,5,5,1},{3,2,4,3},{4,9,7,8}};
```

I want to order this vector by the 4th(last) value in vector value. So the outcome will be like :

```
{{2,5,5,1},{3,2,4,3},{1,10,5,4},{4,9,7,8}};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for the comparator:

```
std::sort(begin(tmp), end(tmp), [](auto const& inner1, auto const& inner2)
{
    // Note: No checking if the sizes are zero, should really be done
    return inner1.back() < inner2.back();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That should do it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> tmp = {
      {1, 10, 5, 4}, {2, 5, 5, 1}, {3, 2, 4, 3}, {4, 9, 7, 8}};

      std::sort(tmp.begin(),tmp.end(), [](auto a, auto b){return a[3]<b[3];} );
}
```